# Upstream text-to-speech cloud providers in European Portuguese

Tags: rest, speech-synthesis

I want to synthesize text in European Portuguese to sound. I am looking for a comprehensive list of upstream text-to-speech cloud providers that

- support European Portuguese (not Brazilian Portuguese)
- has either a REST API or a client library
- is "upstream", i.e. synthesizes the audio itself instead of calling other providers

Here is the list of all such services that I found:

- Google text-to-speech
- Amazon Polly
- Microsoft Cognitive Services
- murf.ai (not sure if it's upstream)

IBM Watson is missing because it lacks European Portuguese. Other providers use these upstream ones. For example, BeyondWords.io is one downstream provider, as their  [documentation](https://docs.beyondwords.io/docs-and-guides/content/voices/standard-voices) says:

> Standard voices are voices available on BeyondWords but provided by third parties such as Microsoft, Amazon and Google.

Other examples of downstream providers are Lovo.ai, Listnr.ai, Synthesia.io, and play.ht .

To avoid the XY problem: the reason I am looking for such a list is that I've been searching for one specific text-to-speech voice (Fernanda in European Portuguese) and haven't found it among any of the above providers.

Is there an upstream text-to-speech provider (other than Google, Amazon, Microsoft and murf.ai) that I have overlooked?

Comment: And now, two weeks later, Fernanda is listed as a voice by Microsoft: https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/voicegallery . So the issue was, probably, that I was a bit early: the downstream providers had early access to this voice, and it's now available to the public.